# Dump v8 JIT output from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, jit, v8

Can node.js (or some other v8 interface or wrapper around v8) output the generated assembly from the v8 JIT?

I'd like to see what the generated assembly looks like for various snippets.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't output anything: `node --expose-debug-as=d -e "function f(){return 1;}; d.Debug.disassemble(f)"`

Comment: is there a particular snippet you would like to investigate?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to ensure that node.js is built with V8 disassembler enabled.  Debug builds will have it enabled by default. For release builds (in recent enough node that uses GYP build) you can enable it by doing:

```
GYP_DEFINES="v8_enable_disassembler=1 v8_object_print=1" ./configure
```

and rebuilding node.

When disassembler is enabled you can use flags like `--print-code`, `--print-code-stubs`, `--print-opt-code` and `--code-comments` to check out the code generated by V8.

If you would like to investigate IR used by optimizing compiler use `--trace-hydrogen` and look at `hydrogen.cfg` (it can be viewed with C1 Visualizer).

Comment: Is this info still up-to-date?

Comment: @OleksiiRudenko yes, mostly. why? These days node comes with disassembler enabled by default in both release and debug (https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/common.gypi#L21). Also I recommend using IRHydra (http://mrale.ph/irhydra/2) instead of C1 Visualizer - but otherwise all flags are the same.

Comment: IRHydra looks really cool! Thanks, it's good to know that I don't need to re-compile node now. I wonder if IRHydra integrates with Benchmark.js? I mean can it exclude irrelevant benchmark.js code from the analysis? And does it really make sense to capture compilation artifacts from benchmarks directly or it makes sense to create isolate examples?

Comment: @OleksiiRudenko no it does not exclude anything - it's agnostic about the code you are looking at, it's actually quite hard to determine what's relevant and what's not. The answer to your second question depends at what kind of code you are looking at. In some cases you'll need isolated example, in some cases (micro)benchmark gives enough data - there is no universal answer when you decide to optimize on such a low level.